# How can I add a trailing slash to a virtual host?

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, proxypass

Clearly I don't know what I'm doing because I've been at this one for hours. I have an apache virtual hosts configuration and am mapping subdirectories to different servers. for instance:

```
<Location /example>
ProxyPass http://192.168.1.6/content/
ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.6/content/
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Location>
```

if I type example.com/example/ in my browser, I can see the content at 192.168.1.6. If I type example.com/example, I cannot. What must I add to this configuration to put a trailing slash automatically so that this works?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard Rewrite rule placed in your vHost.

```
Rewrite /bar http://example.com/bar/
```

That should do what you want to.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a rewrite in .htaccess to redirect the non-trailing slash URL to the trailing slash one.

Comment: I know and I have scoured the documentation but can't seem to figure the proper way to write a rewrite rule in the context of the <location> that will do this correctly. The problem is this backend server has all of it's links like "images/image.jpg" and without the trailing slash I get "example.com/exampleimages/image.jpg.

Comment: why did you downvote my answer? I know it  probably didn't answer your question, but as far as I am concerned, you can do re-writes in .htaccess to fix these type of issues.